# Create NSGridView programmatically

Tags: cocoa, nsview, appkit

As NSGridView isn´t available in Interfacebuilder, I tried to create one programatically.
I tried like this:

```
 class ViewController: NSViewController { 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()     

        let lb1 = NSTextField(labelWithString: "Label1")
        let lb2 = NSTextField(labelWithString: "Label2")
        let lb3 = NSTextField(labelWithString: "Label3")
        let lb4 = NSTextField(labelWithString: "Label4")
        let lb5 = NSTextField(labelWithString: "Label 5 long text ...")
        let bu = NSButton(title: "Button", target: nil, action: nil)

        let empty = NSGridCell.emptyContentView

        let gridView = NSGridView(views:
        [
        [empty, lb1],
        [empty, lb2],
        [lb3, lb4],
        [lb5],
        [bu],
        ])
    self.view.addSubview(gridView)
  }
```

But I only get  a blanc Window - what´s going wrong?

Comment: What is the frame of `gridView`?

Comment: added: gridView.frame = self.view.frame  //seems to work

Comment: why is the setting of the frame needed? In NSStackview, it´s not I think.

Comment: I think `NSStackview` autoresizes to fit around the subviews and `NSGridView` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of gridView to false and add constraints

```
gridView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
   // Your constraints
])
```

Or you can set the frame manually